# Finding a Average of an Array of Integer

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, loops, average

I have this code

```
    Dim intPerson As Integer

    For Each intPerson In intAge

    Next
```

intPerson holds a different number every time the loop is executed because intAge is an array. Is there a way I can find the average of intPerson by adding each number each time and then dividing it by the amount of numbers there are in the array?

Comment: You don't need to dimension the iterator in a `For Each` loop.

Comment: Yeah that. My brain is was being a potato. What I should have typed was: "You don't need to `Dim` the iterator of a `For Each` loop beforehand."

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use Linq:

```
    'create an array with some sample ages
    Dim intAge As Integer() = {22, 34, 56, 87, 19}
    'find the average
    Dim averageAge = intAge.Average 'averageAge = 43.6
```

If you wanto do this longhand you can sum up the values and divide by the number:

```
    Dim totalAges As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To intAge.Count - 1
        totalAges += intAge(i)
    Next
    averageAge = totalAges / intAge.Count 'averageAge = 43.6
```